# why Request URL changes when same origin policy is disabled in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have 2 ajax requests one to a local file (text.txt) and other to www.google.com.

Here are the request headers, when security is enabled (normal case).

**Ajax request to local file:**

```
GET http://localhost:8080/TestWeb/text.txt HTTP/1.1
```

**Ajax request to google.com:**

```
GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/TestWeb/temp.html
User-Agent: ******
```

second ajax request fails because of same origin policy. And this is all the request headers look. Why aren't there any other fields?

When same origin policy is disabled. Both succeeds.

**Ajax request to local file:**

```
GET /TestWeb/text.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: 
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8080/TestWeb/temp.html
```

**Ajax request to google.com**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: 
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8080/TestWeb/temp.html
```

Why the change from

`GET http://localhost:8080/TestWeb/text.txt` **to** `GET /TestWeb/text.txt`
and
`GET http://www.google.com/` **to** `GET /`

Comment: `GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1` only makes sense when using a HTTP proxy... otherwise it's invalid. The hostname always goes into the `Host` header. So I doubt it's related to SOP being enabled/disabled...

Comment: i didn't get it. I'm not using http proxy.